# Facebook Application in C#

Tags: c#, facebook

How to get number of likes for a particular group or total number of members in a particular group from face book using C#.

I am total new to this kind of real time programming. Please help with examples. thanks in advance.

Comment: Google is your friend. http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Facebook+API+C%23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get started is to look into Facebook Graph API C# libraries. My personal favorite is [this one](http://hernan.amiune.com/labs/facebook/c-sharp-facebook-graph-api-library.html), since it provides enough abstraction to get going yet retains most flexibility to customize it to your particular needs.

I also recommend looking into FB Graph API reference for Groups [located here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/). Wrapping those calls using the C# library should not be too difficult.